# go live process , account don't support API integration

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to deploy my sandbox app to production, I did the GO live and passed it .
I then need to connect and select a production account to copy my app into but I can't select it,

I get this error:

```
These accounts don't support API integrations. Select a different production account to continue.
```

I searched on the FAQ of go live and forums but I can't find someone talking about this.
if I understand well, why is my account not supporting API integrations?
What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A paid production account that will serve as the management account for the app in the production environment. This account must be an API, Business Pro, or Enterprise account. ISV partners can apply for a free IK management account via the partner program."

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/go-live/

If you are an ISV, you can try to apply for a free account by becoming a partner, fill out https://www.docusign.com/partners/become-partner to start the process.